# Load more items based on filter logic

Tags: jquery

Logic here..

1. On load div container have to show based on the li selected id. Li ID & div ID have to match and show. Others will be hidden.
2. On intial load, it have to show only 3 items (after filtered based ID). On click "load more" link.. it have to show further 6 on each click. Filter based on ID have to maintained.

Thanks in advance for help!!

**HTML:**

```
<ul>
  <li class="slist selected" id="ele1"><a href="javascript:;">Element 1</a></li>
  <li class="slist" id="ele2"><a href="javascript:;">Element 2</a></li>
</ul>


<div class="cwrapper">
  <div class="contentEle">
    <div class="content ele1">
     Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ve...
    </div>
    <div class="content ele2">
     Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ve...
    </div>
  </div>
  <a href="javascript:;" class="load-more">Load more</a>
</div>
```

**JS:**

```
$('.slist').each(function () {
if($(this).hasClass('selected')) {
$('.cwrapper .contentEle > div.content').hide();
var $postDiv = $('.' + $(this).attr('id')).size();
    var $divEle = 3;
    $('.' + $(this).attr('id'):lt('+$divEle+')).fadeIn(600);
    $('div.content:lt('+$divEle+')').show();

    $('.load-more').click(function () {
      $divEle = ($divEle + 6 <= $postDiv) ? $divEle + 6 : $postDiv;
      $('.cwrapper .contentEle > div.content:lt('+$divEle+')').show();
    });    
 }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a simple filter like

```js
jQuery(function($) {
  var $els = $('.contentEle .content').hide(),
    $curr;

  $('.slist').on('click', function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.addClass('selected');
    $curr = $els.filter('.' + this.id).hide();
    $curr.slice(0, 3).show();
    $els.not($curr).hide();
  }).filter('.selected').click();

  $('.load-more').click(function() {
    $curr.filter(':hidden').slice(0, 6).show();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li class="slist selected" id="ele1"><a href="javascript:;">Element 1</a>
  </li>
  <li class="slist" id="ele2"><a href="javascript:;">Element 2</a>
  </li>
  <li class="slist" id="ele3"><a href="javascript:;">Element 3</a>
  </li>
  <li class="slist" id="ele4"><a href="javascript:;">Element 4</a>
  </li>
</ul>
<div class="cwrapper">
  <div class="contentEle">
    <div class="content ele1">1:1</div>
    <div class="content ele1">1:2</div>
    <div class="content ele1">1:3</div>
    <div class="content ele1">1:4</div>
    <div class="content ele1">1:5</div>
    <div class="content ele1">1:6</div>
    <div class="content ele1">1:7</div>
    <div class="content ele1">1:8</div>
    <div class="content ele1">1:9</div>
    <div class="content ele1">1:10</div>
    <div class="content ele1">1:11</div>
    <div class="content ele1">1:12</div>
    <div class="content ele2">2:1</div>
    <div class="content ele2">2:2</div>
    <div class="content ele2">2:3</div>
    <div class="content ele2">2:4</div>
    <div class="content ele2">2:5</div>
    <div class="content ele2">2:6</div>
    <div class="content ele2">2:7</div>
    <div class="content ele2">2:8</div>
    <div class="content ele2">2:9</div>
    <div class="content ele2">2:10</div>
    <div class="content ele2">2:11</div>
    <div class="content ele3">3:1</div>
    <div class="content ele3">3:2</div>
    <div class="content ele3">3:3</div>
    <div class="content ele3">3:4</div>
    <div class="content ele3">3:5</div>
    <div class="content ele3">3:6</div>
    <div class="content ele3">3:7</div>
    <div class="content ele3">3:8</div>
    <div class="content ele4">4:1</div>
    <div class="content ele4">4:2</div>
    <div class="content ele4">4:3</div>
  </div>
  <a href="javascript:;" class="load-more">Load more</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi Mr. Arun.. one more help needed.. If item less than 3 in total for specific id means.. have to remove "load more" link.. Can u pls suggest me from your code?

Comment: Thanks bro :) Its working.. But.. small clarification needed.. When we add this code in CMS.. click function works fine. But on load our logic not working.. Not sure why? Same logic works fine on HTML version. Is there a way to check whether id for list elements are loaded already?